# How to implement delay for created pseudo instructions in gem5

Tags: gem5

I already implemented a new pseudo instruction to X86 isa in order to improve sha256 algorithm running time.
now I want to set a delay time for this new pseudo instruction but I don't know how to do it.

I already tried using speed function in implementing pseudo function in pseudo_inst.cc, but it is not working and number of ticks remains the same!

I actually run the execFile generated from compiling c file by command below:

```
~/gem5$ ./build/X86/gem5.opt cofigs/sample/Simple.py -c /home/myname/execFile
```